# Pick specific lists from a list of lists

Tags: prolog

I want to set a predicate to_buy(Goods,Offers,Price,Quality), which is true when a list Offers, with total price of Price and total quality of Quality, but i want exactly the products of the Goods. If there is no list of offers which can cover exactly the products of Goods, I won't buy anything at all, and the predicate fails. For example:

I've tried to find all the subsets of Goods that are packages and store them in a List, then find which from them if i append them and msort them return the Goods.
I have packages that are like that:

```
packages([products],Price,Quality).
packages([1,2,3],10,5).

to_buy(Goods,Offers,Price,Quality):-
   findall(X,( subset(X,Goods), package(X,Price,Quality)),List),
   setof( (X,Y),
           (  member(X,List),
              member(Y,List),
              append(X,Y,AList),
              msort(AList,Goods)
           ),Offers).
```

What I expect is in the following screenshot:
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI93Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your setof and sort dance a little confusing. My implementation uses some SWI functions from the `library(lists)` but it will autoload.

We must always start with a base case:

```
to_buy([], [], 0, 0).
```

This says if we aren't buying anything, there are no offers, the price and quality are zero. Now the recursive case:

```
to_buy(Goods, [Package|OtherPackages], TotalPrice, TotalQuality) :-
    %% choose a package
    package(Package, Price, Quality),

    %% this package is a subset of the goods we need
    subset(Package, Goods),

    %% after buying this package, we will still need RemainingGoods
    subtract(Goods, Package, RemainingGoods),

    %% recur on the remaining goods
    to_buy(RemainingGoods, OtherPackages, Subtotal, SubtotalQuality),
    TotalPrice is Subtotal + Price,
    TotalQuality is SubtotalQuality + Quality.
```

So the big idea here is also using `subtract/3` to give us the set difference. Since we know Package is a subset of Goods, we're not buying anything we don't need (i.e. an offer for `[1,2,5]` won't be chosen if we're trying to buy `[1,2,3,4]` because `[1,2,5]` is not a subset of `[1,2,3,4]`). We can then simply recur on the set difference and then do our bookkeeping on what comes back from the recursive call.

I tested with this database:

```
package([2,4], 7, 5).
package([1,3], 3, 8).
```

and this query:

```
?- to_buy([1,2,3,4], Offers, Price, Quality).
Offers = [[2, 4], [1, 3]],
Price = 10,
Quality = 13 ;
Offers = [[1, 3], [2, 4]],
Price = 10,
Quality = 13 ;
false.
```

Comment: Yeap worked fine, I was so keen on finding a solution with findall/3 or setof/3 predicates that I totally missed the recursion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KonstantinosManolis no problem, always glad to help. You can do some pretty cool things with `setof/3` and friends, especially with the new [library(yall)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall).